# Clarification in using Solr

Tags: solr

From [this guide](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) I did the following steps :

1. Copied the files I need to post to exampledocs (Where post.jar is present) .
2. Used `java -Dauto -jar post.jar *.doc *.xls *.pdf` command to post the documents to `solr` .
3. Then using this localhost:8983/solr/select?q=Gradient I was able to query the document .

My Question is that whether the documents which I have posted are been indexed ?
I get the doubt  because i have never defined any schema for it . 
and When I upload large number of documents and query it , Will it be fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are being indexed.  There is a pre defined schema in the schema.xml file that it will be using.

I have found search times to be very fast using Solr, with tens of thousands of docs.

**EDIT**
Here are the set-up guides I was referring to:

Solr set-up : http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html
Nutch Crawling Web (Do first) : http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html
Nucth crawling filesystem (Do Second) :  http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-nutch-to-crawl-filesystem.html

Comment: ok , i read in some portals that the way i post data using post.jar is not advisable all time . Can u suggest me any steps to do the same or is this itself is fine ? @Allan Macmillan

Comment: I set up an Apache Nutch crawler to crawl my filesystem, Nutch has built in integration with Solr which it can transfer the files to Solr for Solr to index and store.  Then used web services to create a search engine.  I wrote a blog on how I set it up which I will post above